I can't get solc to work on vs code
I am trying to use "compile_source" and it doesn't work, solcx is installed and is the latest version:
this is the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Matteo\Python_web3_Infura_first_time.py", line 57, in <module>
    compiled_solidity = solcx.compile_source(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\solcx\main.py", line 101, in compile_source
    return _compile_combined_json(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\solcx\main.py", line 257, in _compile_combined_json
    solc_binary = get_executable(version=solc_version) if solc_binary is None else solc_binary
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\solcx\install.py", line 186, in get_executable
    raise SolcNotInstalled(
solcx.exceptions.SolcNotInstalled: Solc is not installed. Call solcx.get_installable_solc_versions() to view for available versions and solcx.install_solc() to install.

this is the code I'm trying to run.
compiled_solidity = solcx.compile_source("""contract HelloWorld {
string public message;
constructor() {
    message = "Hello World";
}
function setMessage(string memory _message) public {
    message = _message;
}
function sayMessage() view public returns (string memory) {
    return message;
}}""", output_values = ["abi", "bin"])
print(compiled_solidity)

I am having trouble copying this piece of code here, there are no indentation errors in the vs code version of this.
I can't get this to work and I am very frustrated by it.

The error says that the compiler solc isn't installed. It says that can be achieved by solcx.get_installable_solc_versions(). Can you try if that work?
